# ios push notification certificates with Back4App

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, parse-server, back4app

I need to build an update for an iOS application that uses Back4App as backend and we have some push notifications integrated.

The previous version of the app wasn't created by me so I don't have the private key of the previous Push Notification Certificate and I had to recreate them both for Development and Production.

So my questions are:

1. If I upload the new Push Notification Certificates then will the old versions of the app continue working?
2. This seems to be a bug in the Back4App Dashboard, because I have added the new certificates, but I can't remove the older ones.
   If I try to remove a certificate with the X button the I receive a Forbidden (403) error in the error console of the browser and the removed certificates keeps re-appearing when I refresh the window of the browser. (see attached screenshot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are generating the new certificate with a new bundle id, you should keep both certificates uploaded there.

Parse stores in the Installation table the bundle id that the client is using and use the correct certificate for each of them.

Therefore existing users will keep using old certificates and new users (also the existing users that have already updated their apps) will start using the news ones.

Regarding the bug, could you please report it in the [web-site](https://www.back4app.com) chat together with your app id?